# Create a function that uses a list as an argument to extract rows from a CSV

Tags: python, list, function, parameters

I'm trying to pass a list as an argument to a function that will grab a row from a csv if it contains a string in the list provided. I can't get the index to change on itemA.  It only prints the last item of the list!

```py
GAS=[
"SUNOCO",
"CUMBERLAND",
"MOBIL"]
gasLength=len(GAS)
print(gasLength)

def parseData(csvToParse = transactionsCSV, itemA="", itemB=""):
#For Loop to append to CSV
    for row in csvToParse:
        if itemA in row[3]:
            csv_personA.writerow([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]])
            print(row[3])
            print(itemA)
        elif itemB in row[3]:
            csv_personB.writerow([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]])

#This Was suggested but still only returns the GAS index of 0
for counter, _ in enumerate(range(gasLength)):
    parseData(csvToParse=transactionsCSV, itemA=GAS[counter], itemB="")



for _ in range(gasLength):
    x = gasLength-1
    parseData(csvToParse=transactionsCSV, itemA=GAS[x], itemB="")


# My first attempt is below!!!
#Get gas purchases

def parseGasStations():
    x = 0
    itemsToCheck = row_count*gasLength
    print(itemsToCheck)
     #while x is less than total of items in the main csv times the number of items in the gas array.
    while x < itemsToCheck:
        a = 0
        y = 0
        #While a is less than the total number of rows in the main 
        while a < row_count: 
            print(GAS[y])
        for _ in range(gasLength):
            parseData(csvToParse=transactionsCSV, itemA=GAS[gasLength-1], itemB="")
            if y != gasLength-1: 
                y += 1
            elif y == gasLength-1:
                y = 0
            a += 1
        x += 1
parseGasStations()
```

[csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQso7.png)

The output is only appending the MOBIL stations to the CSV and not indexing through the list like I thought it would.

Comment: Can you explain little bit what is the actual output you would be expecting and also little bit about the input (if you can give an example)

Comment: I just added more code above...  I'd like to pull the items in GAS from a csv that contains the items.  For some reason I'm unable to iterate through GAS,  I'm only able to return the initial index value no matter what I try.

Comment: Can you show what an example row looks like?

Comment: POS DEBIT 5/17/19 Checking SUNOCO ANYWHERE IL -20.2.  is returned from running for counter, _ in enumerate(range(gasLength)):
    parseData(csvToParse=transactionsCSV, itemA=GAS[counter], itemB="")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want to use a numeric iteration counter with your iteration, you could do the following.

```py
for counter, _ in enumerate(range(gasLength)):
    parseData(csvToParse=transactionsCSV, itemA=GAS[counter], itemB="")
```

Enumerate returns a tuple containing a counter and the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fluxens I was able to figure this out!
Here's a function that takes a list as a parameter and indexes through all the items!

```py
GAS=(
"SUNOCO",
"CUMBERLAND",
"MOBIL",
"BESTWAY",
"AMORE FUEL")
gasLength=len(GAS)

def parseData(csvToParse="", catagory=(), catagorySize=""):
    #For loop to check each row in master csv
    for row in csvToParse:
        #For loop to index through catagory items to look for in each row
        for counter, _ in enumerate(range(catagorySize)):
            if catagory[counter] in row[3]:
                csv_mark.writerow([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]])
                print(row[3])
                print(catagory)

parseData(csvToParse = transactionsCSV, catagory=GAS, catagorySize=gasLength)
```